# Uploading Files to Planning Center Online API Using CURL/Python

Tags: python, api, curl

Trying to understand, Planning Center API and cURL/Python. Noob to all of it. I am trying to upload a file to planning center API. When I upload the file, I want to include a file name. The [documentation](https://developer.planning.center/docs/#/overview/file-uploads) says to use the following command to upload files:

```
curl -u app_id:secret -X POST -F 'file=@/path/to/file.png' https://upload.planningcenteronline.com/v2/files
```

from that you receive the following sample response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "File",
      "id": "us1-16207df7-b6cc-4abe-ca1a-306c6f7e423d",
      "attributes": {
        "source_ip": "70.128.100.145",
        "md5": "e178604e5083cc23782f34650a49b025",
        "content_type": "image/png",
        "file_size": 48341,
        "name": "file.png",
        "expires_at": "2016-05-23T23:13:32Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I upload the file, I want to be able to pass the file name. How can I do that? I was told I should be able to, but not sure what that would look like.

Comment: How is this question related to Python? And what did you try to obtain the response the documentation says you should expect? What was your result, and how does it differ from your expectations?